# Why is there no uniform initializer for array?

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

Supposed I want to dynamically allocate heap with array:

```cpp
auto my_arr = new int[3] {3, 4, 5};

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    std::cout << my_arr[i] << ' ';

delete[] my_arr;
```

Output:

```
3 4 5
```

When I use without `new` like:

```cpp
auto my_arr = int[3]{3, 4, 5};
```

It throws an error.

Alternatives:

```cpp
auto my_arr = std::array{3, 4, 5}; // deduces into `std::array<int, 3>`
auto my_arr2 = {3, 4, 5};          // deduces into `std::initializer_list<int>`
```

What is the reason why the built-in array has no initialization (constructor-like) when the `new` expression is permitted?

Comment: It's the same reason that `int x[3] = {3,4,5}; int y[3] = x;` doesn't work - you can't copy arrays.

Comment: And the answer to why we can't copy arrays is a combination of "for historical reasons" and "it's much harder to change than people think".

Comment: And this is why we have, and should use, `std::array`.  It's even easier to use with C++17's CTAD.

Comment: Simple answer History of C++ starting from C in 1980 and ending on C++17. C array is not assignable that is why `auto my_arr = int[3]{3, 4, 5};` can't work.